# null object reference on data binding

Tags: java, android, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to use data-binding on a MVVM android project.

I have a login class called `LogginActivity` and the View model that is `LogginMV`

With the debugger, I know that the following line causes a 
    `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.ledeme.animekeeper.databinding.ContentActivityLoginBinding.setLoginVM(org.ledeme.animekeeper.LogginMV)' on a null object reference`.

This is the line :

```
((ContentActivityLoginBinding) DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login))
                .setLoginVM(logginMV);
```

I checked and I know that logginMV isn't null.

I can't figure out what is the null object reference, that's what I need help for.

Comment: In your case, ((ContentActivityLoginBinding) DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login)) is coming null. You have to fix that.

Comment: @Ketan doyou have an idea on what could cause that? the context? the layout?

Comment: sorry I haven't worked on Android but Java... so I could identify where the null is but not why the null is! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I don't know if this is common for all android developers but in my layout folder, I have 2 layouts per activities: one for landscape and one for the other view. They are both named the same way (in my case `activity_login`)and they both include another layout `content_activity_login` that contains pretty much everything for the view.

I had to use `content_activity_login`

```
((ContentActivityLoginBinding) DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.content_activity_login))
            .setLoginVM(logginMV);
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you can add an "id" field to the parent layout tag that included the content layout, e.g.

    android:id="@+id/included_content_activity"

and then reference it from the original data binding you had: ((ActivityLoginBinding) DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login)).IncludedContentActivity.setLoginVM(logginMV);